# Matrix Algebra: Distributive Dilemma

Tags: linear-algebra

So I am trying to prove the expression $A^{-1}+B^{-1}$ is non-singular by showing that $(A^{-1}+B^{-1})^{-1}=A(A+B)^{-1}B$, given $A$, $B$, and $A+B$ are all non-singular matrices. I encountered a step where I had to rearrange the multiplication of an expression. Specifically, I was supposed to go from $(A^{-1}(A+B))^{-1}$ to $((A+B)A^{-1})^{-1}$. Is this move considered "legal" in the matrix world? At the basic level, I know $AB\neq BA$ because of how matrix multiplication works.

Edit: Here is the proof that I did.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1GwQ.jpg)

Edit #2:

The original way it was supposed to be done was going from $A(A+B)^{-1}$ to $((A+B)A^{-1})^{-1}$

Comment: Show your proof attempt, including the step you mention.

Comment: The move you speak of is an instance of commuting $A^{-1}$ with $B$, which in general is not allowed.

Comment: This second identity you mentioned *is* true in general, for any group. Notice that, since inverses are unique, you just have to show a certain product is the identity matrix...

Comment: That move under question is illegal. (It is unclear what means "supposed to go from ... to...") First of all remove the $-1$ power and what remains is a commutativity relation for $A^{-1}$ and $(A+B)$. Which may or may not be true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is true is that (if $A$ and $B$ are invertible) $A (A^{-1} + B^{-1}) B = B + A = A + B$.  Thus if $A + B$ is also invertible,
$$ (A + B)^{-1} = (A (A^{-1} + B^{-1}) B)^{-1} = B^{-1} (A^{-1} + B^{-1})^{-1} A^{-1}$$
so $$(A^{-1} + B^{-1})^{-1} = B (A + B)^{-1} A$$